# Issues with groupingBy method in java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have to create this method `getRentals`, which given a book id, it should return a `SortedMap<String,String>`. The map's key is the reader id and the value is a string with this format "DD-MM-YYYY DD-MM-YYYY", these two dates represent the starting and ending date of the rental of the book.
I wrote this code but I'm having some issues, I probably haven't understood well how groupingBy works...

```java
public SortedMap<String, String> getRentals(String bookID) throws LibException {
    Book b = this.idsColl.get(bookID);

    SortedMap<String, String> res = b.getRentalsList().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Rental::getReaderId,
            r->{
                String start = r.getStartDate();
                String end = r.getEndDate();
                return start+" "+end;
            }));
    return null;
}
```

The idsColl is a map where I associate each unique book id to a book object.
These are the attributes of Rental:

```java
private String readerId;
private String bookId;
private String startDate;
private String endDate;
```

These are the attributes for the book class:

```java
private String copy_id;
private String title;
private boolean rented=false;
private LinkedList<Rental> rentals = new LinkedList<>();
```

Could you please help me understand what am I doing wrong?

I was expecting to get the map with all the readers who rented the book associated with the string containing the starting and ending dates of the rental.
Eclipse gave me this message: The method `groupingBy(Function<? super T,? extends K>, Collector<? super T,A,D>)` in the type `Collectors` is not applicable for the arguments `(Rental::getReaderId, (<no type> r) -> {})`.
Also Eclipse seems blaming at the lamba expression.

Comment: The error *(roughly)* states what the problem is--did you check out the Javadocs for `groupingBy`, specifically parameter ordering?

Comment: Seems like you want to prepare a lookup for `readerId` to its other `Rental` detail(`Map<String, List<Rental>> readerIdLookUpForBook`), it would suffice in this case to not try to over-optimize by performing a mapping unless you practically have other attributes in `Rental` which are hidden from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`groupingBy` will always collect several elements and combine them into the map values. I think you're better off with `toMap`. Unfortunately, that leaves you with the overload that also requires a merge function: [toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, mergeFunction, mapFactory)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Supplier)). In other words - you don't get the default merge function for free that throws an exception if the key function doesn't result in unique keys.

```java
public SortedMap<String, String> getRentals(String bookID) throws LibException {
    Book b = this.idsColl.get(bookID);

    return b.getRentalsList()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Rental::getReaderId,
                r -> r.getStartDate() + " " + r.getEndDate(),
                (u, v) -> {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("found non-unique keys");
                },
                TreeMap::new
            ));
}
```

---

I got annoyed that I have to write the merge function if I want to provide a supplier, so I wrote [stream-utils](https://github.com/robtimus/stream-utils) that has a collector that provides this merge function internally:

```java
public SortedMap<String, String> getRentals(String bookID) throws LibException {
    Book b = this.idsColl.get(bookID);

    return b.getRentalsList()
            .stream()
            .collect(AdditionalCollectors.toMapWithSupplier(
                Rental::getReaderId,
                r -> r.getStartDate() + " " + r.getEndDate(),
                TreeMap::new
            ));
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I solved the problem using toMap, but I was wondering if you can give me an advice: when do you think is better using the groupingBy method and when toMap?

Comment: @Mattia `groupingBy` should be used you want to map multiple stream elements to one single map key. The collector doesn't have to return a list, set or other collection; it can also be something as simple as a String (`joining`) or number (`counting`). `toMap` should be used if every stream element should result in a single map entry.

Answer (score 0):

`groupingBy` by default returns a `HashMap`. You very likely wanted to return with something like `TreeMap` via `Collectors#groupingBy(Function<T, K>, Supplier<M>, Collector<? super T, A, D>)`, for key `K`, map `M`, stream element `T`, and the downstream collector:

```
public SortedMap<String, String> getRentals(String bookID) throws LibException {
    Book b = this.idsColl.get(bookID);
    return b.getRentalsList().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Rental::getReaderId, //map stream element to key
            TreeMap::new, //supply the map type
            Collectors.mapping( //downstream - map elements to a list of values
                r -> r.getStartDate() + " " + r.getEndDate(), //map element to new value
                Collectors.toList() //collect values in a list
            ));
}
```

Comment: In this way I should get a SortedMap<String,List<String>> instead of  SortedMap<String,String> tho...
Is mapping appropriate also to get a primitive type instead of a collection?

Comment: Mapping in this case would be for mapping individual map entries to the elements that you wish to collect in the downstream collector (in this case, `Collectors.toList()`). So the above states that you want to map e.g. `r -> r.getStartDate() + " " + r.getEndDate()`, then collect it into a list. I've edited the question to use your actual example.

Comment: This won't compile for the reason that you are mapping the values to a `List<String>` and returning a `SortedMap<String, String>`.

Comment: Aha indeed. I'll need to revisit this question tomorrow morning, think there might've been a conceptual miss on my answer. This example's intention is using groupingBy and gathering to a `List<String>`, which will need an adjustment.